# Risc v Instruction format

Tags: computer-architecture

Why do you think the Immediate type instructions are limiting its immediate values to only 12 bits, while upper immediate type instructions can handle immediate values of 20 bits.

Comment: This site is intended for objectively answerable technical questions.  "Why do you think?" sounds like a request for opinions and discussion.  See our [help/dont-ask].  Have you researched this subject?  What have you found?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to provide an overview in the question of what relevant information you've been able to find, to make this interesting and useful for others: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723

Comment: Without *some* context, both bit-lengths are meaningless.